# Validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

The below code is works using `document.write`. How to display the value `exceeded` in `Label1` and also how to change the background color of TextBox to red (Using JavaScripts) if value exceeded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function limitlength(obj, length) {
        var maxlength = length
        if (obj.value.length > maxlength)
         document.write("Exceeded")        }

</script>

Enter text (max length is 5 characters):
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:textbox ID="TextBox1" onkeypress="return limitlength(this, 5)" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no question being asked here.

Comment: this is clearly homework

Comment: @James - Have you read it? first read it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an ID to the textbox.

```
function limitlength(obj, length) {
    var maxlength = length
    if (obj.value.length > maxlength) {
        document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = "Exceeded";
        document.getElementById("TextboxID").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but backgrondcolor changes to red right from first `keypress`

Answer (score 1):

First, I would pretty up the javascript:

```
function limitlength(obj, length) {
    var maxlength = length;
    if (obj.value.length > maxlength)
     document.write("Exceeded");
}
```

Second, since you are using .NET you will need to use the ClientID property on your textbox control.  And please assign it an ID.  For example, txtBox.

Third, you can change the background color like this:

```
function limitlength(obj, length) {
    var maxlength = length;
    if (obj.value.length > maxlength) {
     document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "Exceeded"; 
     document.getElementById("<%=txtBox.ClientID %>").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to understand the code. How to change background color of TextBox1 to red?